# How to Exclude a Certain Page from Executing This Script?

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript code and I want a certain page not to run this code. Since I am putting this code in the head, it automatically injects in all parts of the website.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
              if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("https://www.website.com") == -1) {
                 document.links[i].href = 'https://www.website.com/go?url=' + document.links[i].href
              }
         }
    }
</script>
```

I want to exclude a page on my website called website.com/checkout and website.com/product

PS. I'm using wordpress.

Edit: Can I also exclude specific external domain for in this script?

Comment: Well, then omit the script from the HTML files you don't want to run it...

Comment: @FZs How? I'm using wordpress to insert that script.

Comment: You haven't ever mentioned you're using WordPress! It's a different story then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a condition that will check page URL and either not execute on some pages, or execute on some pages:

```js
  if (!['/checkout', '/product'].includes(window.location.pathname)) {
    // your script
  }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
if (!['/checkout', '/product'].includes(window.location.pathname)) {
    onload = function () {
         for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
              if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("https://www.website.com") == -1) {
                 document.links[i].href = 'https://www.website.com/go?url=' + document.links[i].href
              }
         }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: If possible, can you please give me the exact code? I'm not too familiar with js. Thanks.

Comment: Added full example

Answer (score 0):

Set a class for the body in the pages you want to exclude from the execution of the script. Let's say the class is "excluded"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    onload = function () {
         if (document.body.className != 'excluded') {
             // your script for only non-excluded  pages
         }
    }
</script>
```

This way, every time you want a page to be excluded you just have to add the excluded class to its body

Comment: How can I add the script mentioned above inside your script?

Comment: Where I put "your script..." include the for-loop you posted in the question.

Comment: If possible, can you please give me the exact code? I'm not too familiar with js. Thanks.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < document.links.length; i++) {
              if (document.links[i].href.indexOf("https://www.website.com") == -1) {
                 document.links[i].href = 'https://www.website.com/go?url=' + document.links[i].href
              }
         }